# Refresh attribute value after html() with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am making start/pause button that works like this:

```
    var btns = document.querySelectorAll(".repairToggle");
    for (i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
      btns[i].addEventListener("click", manageOrderStatus);
    }
    function manageOrderStatus() {
      var func = this.getAttribute("func");
      var btn = this;
      var endpoint = "{% url 'mtn:ajax_repair_toggle' %}";
      $.ajax({
        url: endpoint,
        type: "GET",
        data: {
          'func': func,
        },
        success: function (data) {
          $(btn).html(data);
        }
      });
    }
```

I have start and stop buttons stored in separate `html` files:
work_order_start.html:

```
<div type="button" class="repairToggle" func="start">
  <svg>...</svg>
</div>
```

work_order_pause.html:

```
<div type="button" class="repairToggle" func="stop">
  <svg>...</svg>
</div>
```

In view i render one of the buttons based on the value of `func` attribute:

```
def repair_toggle(request):
    ...
    func = request.GET.get('func')
    if func == 'stop':
        return render(request, 'mtn/work_order_start.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'mtn/work_order_pause.html')
```

The problem is it only works once. After the first click it keeps executing `ajax` call but it sends the same old `func` value in request. How do i fix that?

**UPDATE:**

I figured out the problem. `$(btn).html(data);` only replaces the `svg` element. So the `func` stays the same. If i do this instead:

```
<div type="button" class="repairToggle">
  <svg id='funcButton' func="stop">
</div>
```

How do i get `func` out of `svg`. I tried `this.getElementById('funcButton').getAttribute("func");` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inserting the button inside the original button.

Change work_order_pause.html and work_order_start.html to only contain the svg and add in success function :

```
 if(func == "start"){
    this.setAttribute("func", "stop")
 }
 else{
    this.setAttribute("func", "start")
 }
```